# ps command: how does the 'r' option work? How should be used?

Tags: ps, options

About the `ps` command for the `r` option

According with `man ps` it indicates

```
r      Restrict the selection to only running processes.
```

And according with `ps --help a` it indicates

```
r                   only running processes
```

If in `tty6` is executed the `sleep 5000 &` command and then `jobs` is executed appears

```
[1]+ Running sleep 5000 &
```

it is expected and observe the **Running** term appears. It as both sources of documentation.

Now, if in the same tty is executed the `ps r` command appears:

```
  PID TTY     STAT   TIME COMMAND
 5508 tty6    R+     0:00 ps r
```

Why the `sleep` command does not appear?.

Until here the assumption would be because is a *background process*. If now is executed by simplicity the `yes` command - it prints `y` forever as expected - and it is a *foreground process* . Because `tty6` is blocked by the *yes* command, then if in other tty - for example `tty1` - is executed the `ps -t tty6 r` command then appears:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 5516 tty6     R+     0:21 yes
```

Therefore until here is possible assume that `r` only works for *running* **foreground** process.

Therefore this `r` option is useful to know what script or command/tool (i.e: maven's goal or gradle's task) was executed and still is running for long time, it for a specific tty. Furthermore because in both places of the documentation appear the *"only running processes"* sentence (observe the "processes" **plural**) I am assuming that the following command pattern would be consider it

`ps -t tty3 -t tty4 -t tty5 -t tty6 r`

But I did realise the following, if for each tty shown above is executed the following commands as follows:

```
cmatrix           # it is a screensaver and remains running
man ls            # it remains opened
ping spring.io    # it remains showing in the terminal each echo message
yes > /dev/null   # it remains running but not showing nothing in the terminal
```

If `ps -t tty3 -t tty4 -t tty5 -t tty6 r` is executed then appears:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 5598 tty6     R+     0:05 yes
```

Why the other *foreground processes* were not considered?

**Question**

- How does the `r` option work? - How should be used?

**Purpose/Goal**

According with my understanding there are many processes types such as *"running, zombie, suspended ..."* therefore to list/retrieve/show a specific type of report - the *"running"* category - it should be retrieved theoretically with `r` option.

Furthermore, for example, if was executed a Maven/Gradle command to build/test multiple modules with many options - and it is taking 25 minutes, the terminal window is still showing a lot of lines about the process itself - so after of a time - I need to know what command was executed (and still running) and with what options/parameters - so I though that `r` option is the correct approach to be used - is that the purpose of the `r` option - right?

Comment: I feel like this flag is broken. I now have at least a dozen CPU active processes yet it shows only itself. *How does the r option work? - How should be used?* - why do you need it in the first place? What's your issue? What are you trying to find out? Not all the options of a command are meant to be used, you know :-)

Comment: `ps axr` sometimes shows some processes but it does it very randomly. `top` -> `i` works as intended.

Comment: The `sleep` process isn't _running_, it'll be in the `S` state (interruptible sleep).

Comment: @AndyDalton but the `jobs` output indicates other thing - but what about all the other foreground processes? there were not listed as expected

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov about your questions, see the "Purpose/Goal" section

Answer (score 4):

The `r` option only shows processes that are actually running. Sleep is not in run state but is, unsurprisingly, in the sleep state. The program basically parses your input and calls `sleep()` and does nothing more. There is a difference between a program in the foreground and a program asleep. Foreground and background states are mainly about where it is with a shell, not if it is consuming CPU.

Most of the time, processes don't actually run all that much. If you run top and look at the `S` and `%CPU` fields you can see that the state for most processes is S and the percentage of used CPU time is tiny.

You'd expect the ps `r` option to mean only processes with state `R` but for some reason, it also includes processes of state `D` (uninterruptible sleep). It's been like that since at least 1999, I'm not sure why.

This flag is most likely used now to look for run-away processes. That is where you run `ps r` multiple times and the same process always appears. It's not a definite problem, but you would want to ask why is that process always running.

Remember it is what the state of the process is right at the time you run `ps` (more correctly, when `ps` checks the state of the process). If you run `ps`  every 10 seconds and a process was hammering the CPU for 9.99 seconds except for that moment you ran `ps`, its not a running process as far as that `ps` is concerned.

That would be like checking if neighbours had visitors by glancing out the window every hour. You might catch someone but the chances are slim.

Almost always you don't want to run `ps` and select on run state. If you're trying to figure out what is using most of the CPU, `top` with idle state on (press i) will show what you need. This type of selection asks "have the CPU usage figures changed since last refresh"?

Comment: My main concern is _Why the other foreground processes were not considered?_ if they are running ...

Comment: about _"but you would want to ask why is that process always running"_ - see the "Purpose/Goal" section